# MySQL Workbench crashes when clicking on save icon

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I open Workbench normally, then I make some queries and then I click on save icon.
After clicking the save icon, the platform stop working.

I'm using workbench 6.2.4 on windows 8.1.

---

SOLUTION
It seems the new version 6.3.3.0 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the following URL:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75015

So, I had to install and old version of mysql workbench (6.1.7).

Hope they can fix the problem in future versions.

Comment: Try this to gather more info about the problem: run WB 6.2.5 short before you save things go to the log folder (Help menu -> Locate Log Files). Then save. Do nothing more but check the wb.log file now. Does it contain anything that indicates what the real problem could be? Add the log file as a private attachment to the bug report.

Comment: Ok, thks for the suggestion @MikeLischke. Will do it soon.

Comment: Also please try the latest version, which is 6.3.3.

Comment: Not sure why, but now I'm experiencing the same problem and I'm using the latest version 6.3.3. Grrrrr